# How to set the name of the container when ecs deploys the image

Tags: amazon-ecs

When ECS deploys the container, the name of the container comes as

*ecs-xray-daemon-family2-1-xray-daemon2-f08780e2a097d7dac101*

Is there an option where we can control the name of the container?

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                 PORTS                               NAMES

9957f08908fa        amazon/aws-xray-daemon   "/usr/bin/xray -t 0.…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour       2000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32768->2000/udp   ecs-xray-daemon-family2-1-xray-daemon2-f08780e2a097d7dac101
```

I have mentioned the name of the container in the task definition like this so I would expect the name of the container to be *xray-daemon2*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because the container names in ECS need to be unique to avoid conflicts. Thus there is a code that randomizes parts of the name.  Something roughly like this:

```
containerName := "ecs-" + task.Family + "-" + task.Version + "-" + name + "-" + utils.RandHex()
```

(But you could use the labels in the task ARN to extract the container name that you provided)